# Missing cookie key/value from request headers in one iAP enabled App Engine instance but not the other

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

Context:

- 2 app engine (flex) node servers:
- identical configuration
- Both include the 3 commonly used key/values in the request headers

  - `x-goog-authenticated-user-email`
  - `x-goog-authenticated-user-id`
  - `x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion`
- 1 of them consistently receives a cookie key/value in the request header while the other doesn't.

Notes:

- The cookie `GCP_IAP_UID:xxxxxxx` can (fortunately) also be found in the header: `x-goog-authenticated-user-id`

Question:

- Seeing as to how I can still get to the uid if I need to, this isn't something that is too immediately concerning. But, does anyone know any reason why this could be happening?